# Wann wurde das/der/die meinige veraltet?

Tags: grammar, pronoun, archaism

> Die meinige Frau kocht ein philippinisches Essen.

In welchem Jahre wurde dieses Fürwort veraltet?

Comment: Entweder es veraltete, oder es wurde als veraltet erklärt, welches davon ist Deine Frage? Das Veralten ist ja eher etwas, das über einen Zeitraum hinweg passiert, während die Erklärung als veraltet ja anhand des Copyrights des Dudens, zum Beispiel, sich präzise angeben lässt, aber natürlich von Sprachwerk zu Sprachwerk differieren kann.

Comment: Meinem Sprachgefühl nach werden _meinige, deinige, seinige, ihrige, uns(e)rege, eurige_ und auch _selbige_ fast ausschließlich ohne explizites Objekt verwendet, sondern bildet eine Ellipse: „Die Frau dort kocht ein philippinisches Gericht und die *meinige* ein *selbiges*.“

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ganz ist [meinige](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/meinige) noch nicht veraltet, aber Duden spricht von gehobenem Gebrauch und von "veraltend".

Noch kann man also dieses Pronomen verwenden und lesen, aber es verschwindet langsam aus dem aktiven Wortschatz. Ein genauer Zeitpunkt lässt sich nicht bestimmen, denn das Wort wurde nicht durch irgendeine Reform plötzlich abgeschafft.

Man kann aber in diesem [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=die%20meinige%2Cdie%20meinigen%2Cdie%20meine%2Cdie%20meinen&year_start=1750&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=50&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdie%20meinige%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdie%20meinigen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdie%20meine%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdie%20meinen%3B%2Cc0) ganz gut sehen, wie sich die Verwendung in den dort eingescannten Werken allmählich verschiebt:

[image]

So findet man noch in der Mitte des 19. Jahrhunderts eine etwa gleich häufige Verwendung von "die meinige" und "die meine", während die Verwendung von "die meinige" mit Beginn des 21. Jahrhunderts bereits um den Faktor 10 zurückgegangen ist.

Eine ähnliche Entwicklung, wenn auch später, sieht man für den Plural "die meinen/meinigen" wie auch für die Verwendung im Neutrum (nicht dargestellt). Nur beim Maskulinum war schon früher "der meine" gebräuchlicher als "der meinige".

Comment: "die meinige" als Ausdruck für die Ehefrau höre ich durchaus noch ziemlich oft. "das meinige" (als Ausdruck für "mein Hab und Gut" habe ich durchaus bei meinen Eltern und Großeltern oft gehört, heute nicht mehr.

Comment: Vielleicht noch deutlicher wird die Entwicklung, wenn man nur die [jeweiligen Verhältnisse](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=die+meinige%2Fdie+meine%2Cdie+meinigen%2Fdie+meinen%2Cdas+meinige%2Fdas+meine%2Cder+meinige%2Fder+meine&year_start=1750&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=50) betrachtet. Übrigens könnte das Ergebnis etwas durch das Verb _meinen_ (v.a. im Konjunktiv) verfälscht sein.

Comment: @Crissov: ja, die Ngrams sind da sehr ungenau, aber man kann schon einen gewissen Trend sehen (mehr muss hier ja vielleicht auch gar nicht sein).

Comment: PS: Die [Entwicklung der Verteilung von _deinige_ und _eurige_ mit und ohne Artikel davor](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=meinige%2F_DET_+meinige%2Cdeinige%2F_DET_+deinige%2Cseinige%2F_DET_+seinige%2Cihrige%2F_DET_+ihrige%2Ceurige%2F_DET_+eurige%2C(unsrige%2Bunserige)%2F(_DET_+unsrige%2B_DET_+unserige)&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3) finde ich interessant.

Answer (score -1):

Wie Crissov schon in einem Kommentar schreibt, ist „die meinige Frau“ schlicht falsch, siehe [DWB](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=meinige) zur tatsächlichen Benutzung von „meinige“.

Comment: Mag zwar richtig sein, ist aber keine Antwort auf die (möglicherweise gemeinte) Frage mE.

Comment: @Jan, das Wort ist in der in der Frage gebrauchten Form nie veraltet.

Comment: Editiere doch die Frage zu einer möglichen Form (z. B. »die Meinige kocht philippinisches Essen«).